# Remove a class based on width of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a table with user selected columns. The user has 2 different view options. 1 with everything contained in the body with a scroll bar and 1 with everything expanded and sticky headers. The user can click a button to expand the table. I am using Jquery to add a class to the user table to expand it.

Normal Table -
[image: Normal Table]

Expanded Table -
[image: Expanded Table]

The issue I am having is that if only a couple of columns are selected and the user is in expanded view it looks really strange.
[image: Weird Table]

What I would like to do is if the table's width is smaller that the body(white background) then remove the expanded class and revert to normal view.

I have tried

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('userTable')).width <= window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('siteBody')[0]).width) {
  $('#userTable').removeClass('isExpanded');
  $('.siteBody').removeClass('expandContainer');
}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance and stay safe.

Comment: Please add some relevant ("*[mcve]*") code to the question so we can reproduce your problem without having to guess what, and where, the `userTable` and `siteBody` elements are in relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work with this small change:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('userTable')).width <= window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('siteBody')[0]).width) {
  $("#userTable").removeClass('isExpanded');
  $('.siteBody').removeClass('expandContainer');
}
```

You have to put the jQuery selector #userTable within quotes, otherwise jQuery would not be able to figure out which element to perform the removeClass action for.

Comment: Thanks for that. That was just a typo on my part. The actual code has that. Thanks